# Save nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid as png

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, pgm, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

map_server saves an occupancy grid as a pgm, but is there a way to save the map as a png?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264154/save-nav_msgs/occupancygrid-as-png/) by [mmy227](https://answers.ros.org/users/30437/mmy227/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can convert the pgm to a png with gimp, photoshop, or the `convert` command-line tool. (`sudo apt-get install imagemagick` ;  `convert map.pgm map.png` )

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2